# Execute block of code when a local text file updates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm wondering how I can execute a few lines of code in JavaScript when a local .txt file updates. Thanks!

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: you can use my [watchfile](https://github.com/rndme/watchfile) lib, all it needs is an `<input type=file>`

Comment: @dandavis - Thanks!

Comment: @CawayC [Please do not put `[SOLVED]` or anything like that in question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you've tagged this question [html](/questions/tagged/html) and [html5](/questions/tagged/html5): You can't. Browsers do not provide webpages with any API to monitor the local file system for changes.

You'd need a JS environment which does have access to the local file system to do this, for example: NodeJS, which has the [fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) method.

Comment: But let's say you have specified a file with for example `readTextFile("file:///C:/Desktop/example/file.txt");`, and when the content in that file updates, it execute a few lines of code. Is that possible?

Comment: @CawayC — No, of course not. You can't make up a function name and expect browsers to suddenly give you access to the user's files.

Comment: @CawayC: yes, you can do just that by pinging a populated file input's date property, and re-loading the File if it changes; see my comment for a lib that makes that easy. i find this useful for interfacing binary apps with web apps w/o installs..